# Load iFrame using Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want a

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-Uwjt32NvVA?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="float: right;"></iframe>
```

to load after a div is clicked on.

This is because i don't want it to load (since it is autoplay) before the user navigates to it. It is on autoplay because I can't click on the iFrame video in chrome due to chrome bug.

Something like `onclick="loadvideo();"` will do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery .[load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/);

```
function loadVideo() {
    $('#div').load('<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-Uwjt32NvVA?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="float: right;"></iframe>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append it to a div once the user clicks on the load button:

```
<div id='videoDiv'></div>
<a id='loadVideoButton'>LOAD</a>

<script>
    var loadVideo = function() {
        $('#videoDiv').append("<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/-Uwjt32NvVA?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="float: right;"></iframe>");
    };


    $("#loadVideoButton").click(loadVideo());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
$('div').click(function(){
   $(this).html("<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/-Uwjt32NvVA?rel=0&autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen style=\"float: right;\"></iframe>"
});
```

See this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmENK/)